# GradientDrawable is not working for android L

Tags: android, drawable, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a ImageView and I am setting a gradient drawable in setImageDrawable .till this all work fine  in android L

the problem start when I change the color of the gradient drawable  dynamically  , then it will not  reflect the color in the UI.

it was working fine till API 19 , but got break in android L
It's working when set background from Drawable but when try to change the color from programming using GradientDrawable it's not working in Android L.

```
            GradientDrawable bgShapeRl = (GradientDrawable) mHolder.mRl_button
                    .getBackground();
            bgShapeRl.setColor(Color.parseColor("#f5f5f5"));
            GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable) mHolder.mTxt_count
                    .getBackground();
            bgShape.setColor(Color.parseColor("#cbcbcb"));
```

Comment: I also have same problem in Android L.

Comment: GradientDrawable is working fine,  try it with a simple TextView for example,  then locate where your problem is and update your question

Comment: It's a simple textview in Listview. It's working fine upto Android Kitket.

Comment: The issue is already listed in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75980

Comment: @KDroid try a simple TextView and check if it's working or not

Comment: Yes,It's working with normal textview.

Comment: ListView recycles views. You can't set a value and expect it to persist between layout passes unless you're setting it in your adapter's obtainView method.